# Different centroid values for trapezoid using two different methods?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, centroid

Suppose I have the following trapezoid: [image]

Now, I used two methods to calculate the **x coordinate** of its centroid:

1. $x_c = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4}{4} = \frac{0+0+3+4}{4} = 1.75$

The second method is the weighted method, it involves dividing the trapezoid into a triangle and rectangle, and using the formula:

$x_c = \frac{A_1 \cdot x_{c1} + A_2 \cdot x_{c2}}{A_1 + A_2}$

Where $x_{c1}$ is the x coordinate of the centroid of the rectangle, which is of course 1.5, and $x_{c2}$ is the x coordinate of the centroid of the triangle, which is: $x_{c2} = \frac{3+3+4}{3} = \frac{10}{3}$. $A_1$ is the area of the rectangle and it is $3$, and $A_2 = \frac{1}{2}$

Plugging this in, I get $$\frac{3 \cdot 1.5 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{10}{3}}{3+0.5} = 1.761904762$$

My question is: As much as these two values are close, they aren't identical. I thought that the first formula worked when both bases are parallel to the x-axis, so I naturally thought these two should have the same value. Could someone explain why this is not the case?

Edit: I am using the Center of Sums method for defuzzyfication, the description of which can be found here: [https://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~dsamanta/courses/archive/sca/Archives/Chapter%205%20Defuzzification%20Methods.pdf](https://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/%7Edsamanta/courses/archive/sca/Archives/Chapter%205%20Defuzzification%20Methods.pdf)

Comment: You are mixing up Centroid & Center of gravity. You can try making two triangles ABC ADC & calculate , then try making two triangles ABD & CBD & calculate. You will get more Different Answers. Basically Centroid is average of x-coordinates , while Center of gravity uses weights.

Comment: @Prem I need to use the Center of Sums method for other reasons. I have the formula $\frac{\sum_i^n x_{ci} \cdot A_i}{\sum_i^n A_i}$, where $A_i$ are the areas of each figure, and $x_{ci}$ are the **x coordinates of the geometric center of the area**.

I have trouble figuring out the $x$ coordinate part of the geometric center.

Comment: (1) Where you did you that formula ? You should include the source of your formula which will enable targeted Answers. (2) Either you are using wrong formula Or you are applying the formula wrongly.

Comment: @Prem It's a common defuzzyfication method for fuzzy logic. I'll include it into the post, but take a look here: https://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~dsamanta/courses/archive/sca/Archives/Chapter%205%20Defuzzification%20Methods.pdf

It's the first method described. (Center of Sums).

Comment: I have updated My Answer , to "highlight" where it was going wrong , to give Different values.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this Comment in Answer format because it is getting too long.

### Original Issue :

**You are mixing up Centroid & Center of gravity.**
You can try making two triangles ABC ADC & calculate , then try making two triangles ABD & CBD & calculate. You will get more Different Answers.
Basically Centroid is average of x-coordinates , while Center of gravity uses weights.

### Updated Issue :

It is neither Euclidean geometry nor analytic geometry nor Centroid : It is a defuzzyfication method , where the Answers calculated are not going to correspond to some geometric Center or Center of gravity or ETC.

Document says this about "Center of Sums (COS) Method" :
**In this method, the overlapping area is counted twice.**
Naturally , this is not going to correspond to Centroid.

Document says this about "Weighted Average Method" :
**This method is valid for fuzzy sets with symmetrical output membership functions and produces results very close to the COA method.**
Implicitly & Explicitly , it is saying that each Method will give Different Answer.

There are at least 8 Methods listed , with each giving Different Answer.

It is not valid to compare with Strict Precise Concepts like Centroid & Center of gravity.
It is "fuzzy" logic due to "fuzzy" nature of the calculations involved.
It is Expected that we will get Different Answers via Different Methods here !!

### Settling the Overall Issue :

It is not true that Polygon Centroid is the Average $x$ value of the vertex Co-Ordinates.
Average $x$ Co-Ordinate is valid when we have finite number of Points.
Hence , when we take Polygon (trapezoid) Edges or Polygon (trapezoid) Area , we have infinite number of Points.
We can not use the Average of $x$ Co-Ordinate on those vertex Co-Ordinates.
Hence $1.75$ is wrong & $1.761904762$ is Correct.
In fuzzy logic , that is okay , because we want to use fast calculations to get Close Answers.

### Proof that Averaging is wrong :

[image: CENTROID]

When we have triangle $WYZ$ , we know the Centroid $x$ Co-Ordinate , which is "Stationary".
Let us include a new Point on the Base , to make a Quadrilateral $WXYZ$ , which is Essentially the Same triangle.
We should Expect that Centroid is "Stationary" & will not change.
Yet , we are now adding $4$ numbers & Dividing by $4$.
More-over , $X$ can move along the Base , which will Contribute various $x$ Co-Ordinates to the Average , hence this way to calculate Centroid will not give Same Answer.

**Where is it going wrong ? Answer : Averaging is valid when we have finite number of Points. Averaging is invalid when we have infinite number of Points.**

Why is is still used in fuzzy logic : We want fast calculations to generate Close Answers , not Accurate Answers.